# Admin login not working

Tags: admin, wp-admin, login, wp-login-form

I can't log in as admin on my wordpress site. I've tried to change the password, and a bunch of other stuff, but no result. What happens is that I come back to the log in page, no message. The strange thing is that I can log in as another user, but then I don't have the authority that I need.

I've checked the PHP log files and I can't find anything there.
I've tried to go in private mode, but it doesn't work either.

Suggestions what I should try?

Comment: Try disabling plugins by moving them out of the plugin folder or temporarily renaming the folders (a prefix, for example: 'folder-name' becomes '_folder-name' so you can undo it later)

Comment: Tried it, didn't work.

Comment: Check whether you have capabilities correctly for you admin user, have you mendle with capabilities of the admin directly on DB

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can upload wp-login.php again or change your Admin password with sql query:
UPDATE 'wp_users' SET 'user_pass' = MD5('PASSWORD') WHERE 'user_login' ='admin' LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 1):

What you're saying suggests your tokens are not correct. If I were you I'd try to change the password via phpmyadmin :

```
UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = MD5('newpassword') WHERE user_login = "admin";
```

Change with your login and/or table prefix.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work, tried to change the password the "normal" way, and when I clicked the link that I got in the mail, it says: Sorry, that key does not appear to be valid.
Something seems corrupt.